# 2nd apache server fails to start

Tags: apache-2.2

HI, I have determine that my 2nd server which fail to start because of this entry in conf.
Once I remove this entry, the server start up as normal.

```
Alias /Reports/ "//abc/filedir/a/"
<Directory "//abc/filedir/a/">
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I have a primary apache server which is also pointing to the folder with the same setting. I will like to know why the 2nd server failed to start, is it because the server one has locked the folder. //abc is my NAS server running on window 2003.

Thanks

Comment: Give us error log! Also do you have any specific reason why have 2 apaches?

Comment: hi, 2 is a fail over server, it suppose to be up running when 1 is down. Tested it, 2 can be up running with the entry in that scenario, what puzzled me is why cant 2 start up when 1 is running. The share directory and folder on the win 2003 is set to maximum allowed.

Comment: no error on apache log, the only error I get is win system event log, "<Directory ... is invalid"

Answer (score 0):

I think your apache is running on Windows.

Maybe the first apache is running as service with a normal windows user, while the second apache with the (default) system user, which cannot access network resources.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that both instances of Apache are not trying to listen on the same IP/port. I would also question why you are trying to run two instances. There's nothing technically wrong with running two instances but most things can be done with one instance with less issues.

Comment: Listen port isn't the problem because @ito3 wrote: commenting Alias and directory directives apache starts regular.

Comment: Actually trying to move to a LB setup, this seem to be a problem.